# Colored text along path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have scoured the TikZ documentation, and looked online without success. How does one create colored text along a path in TikZ? I want to create an arc of red text, so one would think this could work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [postaction={decoration={color=red,text along path, reverse path, text align=center, text={This is some text}}, decorate}] (0:1.75cm) arc (0:-180:1.75cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've tried putting the color in various places in the command, but here is no TikZ key for `color` in the text decoration library, so I'm at a loss. Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Use `text color=red` instead of just `color=red`. You are inside the `pgf/decoration` key-path where only specific options can be used. Also see the [manual](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.7).

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [manual](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#sec-50.7), the correct option for setting the text color in a decoration with `text along path` (or related decorations) is `text color`.

Note that the defintion of options depends on where they are called in the key tree (the path-like structure of keys in PGF). Here, you are inside the key tree at `/pgf/decoration` where only specific options are defined such as `text color`.

The following should work (also note the new syntax for the `arc` operator):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[
    postaction={
        decoration={
            text along path, 
            reverse path, 
            text align=center, 
            text color=red,
            text={
                This is some text
            }
        }, 
        decorate
    }
] (0:1.75cm) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, radius=1.75cm];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result would be achieved without calling the decoration as `postaction`, by the way:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[
    decoration={
        text along path, 
        reverse path, 
        text align=center, 
        text color=red,
        text={
            This is some text
        }
    }, 
    decorate
] (0:1.75cm) arc[start angle=0, end angle=-180, radius=1.75cm];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```